# Docker push does not show up in repository

Tags: docker

I have deleted the docker repository and recreated it.
Here is the minimal repoducable example.
The problem is that, the tag doesnt show up in https://hub.docker.com/r/rgbcube/selfharm-linux/tags.

```
[asus@ASUS Downloads]$ git clone https://github.com/RGBCube/selfharm-linux
Cloning into 'selfharm-linux'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 56, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 56 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 44
Receiving objects: 100% (56/56), 137.30 KiB | 990.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (19/19), done.
[asus@ASUS Downloads]$ cd selfharm-linux
[asus@ASUS selfharm-linux]$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  203.3kB
Step 1/3 : FROM debian:stretch
stretch: Pulling from library/debian
a834d7c95167: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:4bb600434787c903886fe33526d19ff33114a33b433a4a4cdbdf9b8543f1ab5d
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:stretch
 ---> 28c1b600f6da
Step 2/3 : COPY bash.bashrc /etc/
 ---> 31874d1780c5
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
 ---> Running in e8f13444edb2
Removing intermediate container e8f13444edb2
 ---> 79ca0bcc8ec4
Successfully built 79ca0bcc8ec4
[asus@ASUS selfharm-linux]$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>       <none>    79ca0bcc8ec4   55 seconds ago   101MB
debian       stretch   28c1b600f6da   3 days ago       101MB
[asus@ASUS selfharm-linux]$ docker tag 79ca0bcc8ec4 rgbcube/selfharm-linux:latest
[asus@ASUS selfharm-linux]$ docker push rgbcube/selfharm-linux:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/rgbcube/selfharm-linux]
f05f0537705d: Pushed 
d05b8af4c7ce: Mounted from library/debian 
latest: digest: sha256:162ca5b9bd628e0a91a6bd28cbfb1eb328007162a175217e513897a9fad7d4b4 size: 736
[asus@ASUS selfharm-linux]$
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the repository on DockerHub and creating a new one with the same name?

Comment: trying that right now

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't show up.

Comment: What is I'm the image, how did you build it, and have you tried pushing it to other registries? Since the repository is public, there's no reason to mask the digests.

Comment: @BMitch ive built the image by cloning the repo ad doing `docker image build .`.

Comment: Can you pull the image from DockerHub once it's been pushed?

Comment: hmm, i can pull it, but it doesn't show up in the tags panel,  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I suspect that's normal behavior. Check DockerHub again in a day or two. If you still don't see your pushed image, then contact DockerHub support.

Comment: It appears to show up in the tag list now. Likely a glitch in Hub's web interface.